# Need help to se the difference between sum for the full month and a number in a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

I work at a transportation company and try to get out some statistics. I have what each car earn each day in a datasheet and I know how much they need to earn to break even. But I don't know how to make it work in my Pivot table.

First of all, sorry for my eventually bad english, it's not my native tounge.

I've set up a datasheet with the cars and how much they earn, which i can get in a neat Pivot table with a bunch of other data. My problem is that I need to know if the car is break even or not each month.

I've tried a calculated field with "Cost" - "65000" (break even in Sek), which works for the months total but looks strange for each day and doesn't work for the grand total because it takes "Total earnings" - "65000".

When I put it in my datasheet with a column of 65000 for each day and then do a calculated field of "Cost" - "Break even" it accumulates and the columntotal is -1000k because of this. But the Grand total works as it should, it takes the sum of each month instead of "Total Cost" - "65000" but beacuse of the accumulation it's wrong.

So i need to either make a calculation where I can divide the "break even sum"/month based on the number of unique dates in set. The dates which that car has been driving. If it is put in the datasheet or in a calculated field works either way for me. But I can't get my head around how to make that happen.

Perhaps someone of you guys can help me out?

This is how my datasheet looks like
[This is how my datasheet looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K2fQ.png)

And this is how the table looks like, "Field 1" is the first one i've tried with "Earnings per day" - "65000". And "Field 2" is the second one with 65k in a column and then a calculated field with "Cost" - "Break even"
[Snip of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAwMd.png)

Comment: Could you post some pictures of your tables as well as the attempts you've tried so far?

Comment: provide better information, code snippets, screenshots pls

Comment: @M.Schalk I've managed to get some pictueres up, and one of them is of the table after the attempts I've made

Comment: @Perazim I'm afraid i dont have any code, but I've added two screenshots